# Parse URL search params to an object array with encoded url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am having trouble parsing a query string into an array when a space is present in one of the values without altering that value:

**Example search param:**

`filters=%7B"value"%3A"test%20ing"%2C"type"%3A"search"%7D%20%7B"dataIndex"%3A"plan"%2C"value"%3A"5b61c72879f4503bfa9e729b"%2C"type"%3A"oid"%7D`

**Parsed result: (string)**

```
{"value":"test ing","type":"search"} {"dataIndex":"plan","value":"5b61c72879f4503bfa9e729b","type":"oid"}
```

**Desired Result: Array**

```
[
  {"value":"test ing","type":"search"}, 
  {"dataIndex":"plan","value":"5b61c72879f4503bfa9e729b","type":"oid"}
]
```

**Attempted Approach**

```
["{"value":"test", "ing","type":"search"}", "{"dataIndex":"plan","value":"5b61c72879f4503bfa9e729b","type":"oid"}"]
```

I have a `space` in between each `object` and was hoping to `split` but when using that approach, it will split the `value` when spaces are present as you can see above.

What would be suggested way to achieve desired result?

Answer (score 0):

The parsed string is not valid JSON - you'll have to manually insert a comma in between the `} {`s to make it valid, after which you can `JSON.parse` it inside of `[]`s:

```js
const input = 'filters=%7B"value"%3A"test%20ing"%2C"type"%3A"search"%7D%20%7B"dataIndex"%3A"plan"%2C"value"%3A"5b61c72879f4503bfa9e729b"%2C"type"%3A"oid"%7D';
const malformedFilters = new URLSearchParams(input).get('filters');
const fixedFilters = malformedFilters.replace('} {', '}, {');
const arr = JSON.parse('[' + fixedFilters + ']');
console.log(arr);
```

That said, it would be better to fix the code that generates this input, if at all possible, so that such a hack isn't necessary, and so that you could just do

```
const arr = JSON.parse(new URLSearchParams(input).get('filters'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh... since you have a search bar and filters, here's how you can combine everything into a single `JSON array` and keep search and individual filters confined within their own `object`s.

Working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/lx8n5x4w4z

**components/SearchForm.js**

```
import filter from "lodash/filter";
import map from "lodash/map";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ParsedURI from "./parsedURI";
import FilterField from "./filterField";
import SearchField from "./searchField";

// initial form state
const initialState = {
  fieldsCount: 1,
  search: { value: "", type: "search" },
  filters: [{ id: 1, dataIndex: "", value: "", type: "" }]
};

export default class SearchForm extends Component {
  state = { ...initialState };

  // handles search input changes
  handleSearchChange = ({ target: { name, value } }) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      search: { ...prevState.search, [name]: value }
    }));
  };

  // handles all filter changes (select, select and input) by their id
  handleFilterChange = ({ target: { id, name, value } }) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      filters: map(
        prevState.filters,
        item =>
          parseInt(id, 10) === item.id
            ? { ...item, [name]: value }
            : { ...item }
      )
    }));
  };

  // adds a new field to filters and updates a field counter
  addField = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      filters: [
        ...this.state.filters,
        {
          id: this.state.fieldsCount + 1,
          dataIndex: "",
          value: "",
          type: ""
        }
      ],
      fieldsCount: this.state.fieldsCount + 1
    }));
  };

  // removes selected filter field by id
  deleteField = id => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      filters: filter(this.state.filters, field => field.id !== id)
    }));
  };

  // resets form to initial state and updates the URL
  handleReset = () =>
    this.setState(
      {
        encodedJSON: "",
        filtersJSON: "",
        ...initialState
      },
      () => this.props.history.replace("/search/")
    );

  // handles form submission
  handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { search, filters } = this.state;

    const arr = [];

    // flatten search and filter options into a single array
    arr.push({ ...search }, ...filters);

    // convert that array to a JSON array
    const filtersJSON = JSON.stringify(arr);

    // convert JSON array to an encodedURI
    const encodedJSON = `filters=${encodeURI(filtersJSON)}`;

    // set to state and push to URL
    this.setState(
      {
        encodedJSON,
        filtersJSON: arr,
        ...initialState
      },
      () => this.props.history.push(`/search/filters?${encodedJSON}`)
    );
  };

  render = () => (
    <div style={{ padding: "5px 20px" }}>
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <SearchField
          value={this.state.search.value}
          handleSearchChange={this.handleSearchChange}
        />
        <p>Select a filter, option, and input a value:</p>
        {map(this.state.filters, ({ id, ...rest }) => (
          <FilterField
            key={id}
            id={id}
            deleteField={this.deleteField}
            filtersLength={this.state.filters.length}
            handleFilterChange={this.handleFilterChange}
            {...rest}
          />
        ))}
        <br />
        <button
          type="button"
          style={{ marginRight: 20, marginBottom: 20 }}
          className="uk-button uk-button-primary"
          onClick={this.addField}
        >
          Add Filter
        </button>
        <br />
        <div style={{ marginTop: 40 }}>
          <button
            type="button"
            style={{ marginRight: 20, marginBottom: 20, float: "left" }}
            className="uk-button uk-button-danger"
            onClick={this.handleReset}
          >
            Reset Form
          </button>
          <button className="uk-button uk-button-secondary" type="submit">
            Submit
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
      {this.state.encodedJSON && this.state.filtersJSON ? (
        <ParsedURI
          encodedJSON={this.state.encodedJSON}
          filtersJSON={this.state.filtersJSON}
        />
      ) : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Example encoded URI string:

```
%5B%7B%22value%22:%22Test%20ing%22,%22type%22:%22search%22%7D,%7B%22id%22:1,%22dataIndex%22:%22topic%22,%22value%22:%22React%20Local%20State%22,%22type%22:%22name%22%7D,%7B%22id%22:2,%22dataIndex%22:%22subcategory%22,%22value%22:%22123456789%22,%22type%22:%22oid%22%7D%5D
```

Example decoded URL string `JSON.stringify(filtersJSON, null, 4)`:

```
[
    {
        "value": "Test ing",
        "type": "search"
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "dataIndex": "topic",
        "value": "React Local State",
        "type": "name"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "dataIndex": "subcategory",
        "value": "123456789",
        "type": "oid"
    }
]
```

Comment: The approach I am taking is in an effort to support multiple filters:

Example: lets say a user uses the search bar on the table and searches "foo" and also then applies a secondary filter on table cell. I would need to know the the name, value, and type and each in order to properly format on backend and build mongodb $match query

Comment: Updated answer to include another approach.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to figure what was desired by utilizing this approach:

**Encode URL Helper:**

```
const encodeUrl = filters => filters.reduce((str, filter) => `${str}${URI.encode(JSON.stringify(filter))}&&`, '')
```

**Format Query Helper:**

```
const formatQuery = query => compact(query.split('&&') || [])
```

**Parse Query:**

```
const filters = URI.decode(this.props.location.search).replace('?filters=', '')
```

**API (passing query filters to api service):**

```
${PLANS_API_ENDPOINT}?filters=[${formatQuery(query)}]
```